# Allow retracting flags on deleted posts even if you can't view deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, retracted-flags

Now that we have the ability to retract flags, I would like to make use of it to retract flags that would most likely be marked helpful but would have no further actionable effect on a post.

### **Problem Case**

Sadly, currently there is no way (that I know of) to retract a flag on a deleted post if you don't have the 10k privilege to view deleted posts. This unfortunately means that some custom moderator flags I've raised sit in limbo until a moderator gets to them and notices that the post has already been handled, and then dismisses them as helpful. That to me sounds like a preventable waste of precious moderator time.

**Example of the problem occurring**:

I happened across a [spam post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253993/how-to-record-a-screencast-from-the-iphone-simulator/39343691#39343691) ([mirror for <10k](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/39511)) that wasn't very obvious spam since there was no link, but spam nonetheless. I decided to raise a custom moderator flag on the post to alert a moderator to the situation, since just a spam flag would probably get declined considering the lacking context.

The user posting the spam was then found to have posted several other posts containing a link and the same text, making this very obvious spam instead. Comments to that effect were posted, and the post was subsequently destroyed by 6 spam flags, yet my flag was still pending.

In this case, my flag serves no further discernible purpose, and all a moderator can do when coming across it is to dismiss it as helpful, since the post has already been handled. I would like to retract this flag and to spare moderators the time it takes to open the post to find out that its already been handled.

### **Proposal**

Allow retracting flags directly from the "Flagged Posts for [User]" menu on your profile.

Comment: Funny that no one has voted to close the question as a tool request.

Comment: I did. But I retracted it.

Comment: I like the feature just because it seems like a hole in the current design, but how many mod flags on deleted posts that need to be retracted are there really?  How much time do you think it would actually save the mods?  Can't be that many at any one time that it would be a huge time saver for the mods.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can only say that its happened to me personally quite a few times that I had flags where I thought "If only I could retract that this has been really pointless and will probably annoy the next mod looking over it". Also the case for when a mod handles a post as brought up by chat and forgets to dismiss flags on it. Maybe a mod can comment on this?

Comment: You're overestimating the amount of time it takes for a moderator to handle these. They don't have to open the post. There's a red background in the queue that indicates the post is already deleted, and they even see the other spam flags that were already handled (greyed out to indicate they're dismissed). It takes a couple seconds to figure out what happened and just dismiss the remaining flags.

Comment: Isn't 'aged away' the stat that indicates non attended flags, so won't be need to moderate it?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307382/allow-retracting-a-moderator-flag-if-the-post-has-been-deleted-and-i-dont-have

Comment: Are you sure it's spam, because quick time player is built in on Apple devices, so why would it be asking you to download an application that Apple computers already come with?

Comment: It's not about that you can't see deleted posts when being under 10k. I have >10k rep and can see the posts but still can't retract my "spam" flags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the userscript in [Michał Perłakowski's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333954/allow-retracting-flags-on-deleted-posts-even-if-you-cant-view-deleted-posts/333960#333960) is no longer available, I have written my own version which can be found here: **[FlagRetractor](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/FlagRetractor.user.js)**

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Hi Samuel! I installed your user script to retract one of my "spam" flags to a deleted question (similar to described in the question as well). But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. When I hit the black "Retract PostOther flag" icon, nothing happens except that the icon disappears and as soon as I refresh the page the flag is still there and the icon appears again. When I push it again the same goes on and on. I posted this as [issue](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues/87) also to the project page of "FlagRetractor" on Github.

Comment: @RobertS fixed, simply update the userscript

Comment: Great. The problem is I got a little problem to reproduce the situation and can be sure that it works. I need a post to flag, a deleted post and a dangling flag. I'll try it at least at the next appropriate post to be flagged and try to retract the flag with your user script. I'll try to keep up-to-date. BTW: Was the problem I described related to an actual issue in the code?

Comment: @RobertS the earlier issue was due to a bug, since spam flags uses a different wrapper element which I did not take into account.

Comment: Does this still work? I wanted to test it on one of the plagiarism questions (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426290) but I don't see the retract button :/

Answer (score 40):

Before this feature gets implemented, you can use [a userscript I wrote](https://stackapps.com/q/7033/38449), which allows you to retract flags directly from the "Flagged Posts for [User]" page in the user profile. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does your script require any min rep to use it?

Comment: @techspider AFAIK, no.

Comment: One day meta.stackoverflow.com will just be a Q&A about programming around the stackoverflow API.  meta.meta.stackoverflow.com will become the place where you discuss how to make posts to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Unfortunately, This user script is no longer available (Error 404 when opening link to Github repository) and also no feedback from OP. :-(

Answer (score -15):

Would it be better to just **auto-resolve any open flags when a post gets deleted**? That would save both moderator time and your own.

Not sure what would happen if a post is reopened though...? Maybe instead of clearing flags, it would be better to **(alternately) just filter closed questions out of the review queue** entirely instead of just styling them. Then if the post is re-opened, the flag comes back into play.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to auto-resolve custom moderator flags, because they are used also for other things than notifying a moderator that the post should be deleted.

Comment: No. Moderator flags can be used as a general communication channel with moderators. The template flags can be auto resolved under certain circumstances, but mod flags should not be automatically resolved.

Comment: I was thinking general user ("template"?) flags (OP doesn't mention moderator flags) - didn't realize mods had *custom* flags, actually. Clearly removing custom flags would be a bad idea. But since there are some other things to consider here in the larger scope, auto-closing or filtering doesn't appear suit the moderator needs anyways.