# Allow to edit a custom mod flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, custom-flags

I recently custom-flagged a post which demonstrates a pattern of bad behavior by a specific user. I flagged one of those posts and simply stated that the user posted others. I didn't attach a link to the other posts in the flag because I didn't have it at the moment.

I value the time and effort of our mods and when I raise a custom flag I always try to add as much details as possible. In this case I guessed it's fine as the mod can just check that user's posts. Still, some time after raising the flag I stumbled again on one of those other posts and really wanted to add it to the flag, but couldn't.

So my question/request is: ***Please allow the option for editing a custom flag***, if it hasn't been reviewed by a mod yet (obviously...).

I can see no harm in this and think it's a win-win: I will have the option to add more details and once a mod acts on the flag it would be easier for them, and I reduce the chances of my flag being declined for lack of details.

Comment: Why not just retract and reflag

Comment: You could also retract the flag and raise it again, right?

Comment: Doesn't retracting blocks you from raising again?

Comment: You can't reflag for the same reason _except_ custom mod flags, which you can do as much as you like

Comment: @Nick well...... Didn't know that little bit of information /facepalm

Comment: @yivi I realize that now, but still. Isn't it easier to be able to just edit straight from the flags page?

Comment: I mean, yeah sure. Not against the FR. Simply that I see very little value on it since it's something that can easily be solved with the current tools. It's an edge case in any case

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Allow editing or deletion of moderator flag comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96026)

Comment: The only use case I see is for users with less than 10k reputation. You need to see the flagged post in order to retract your flag (also see [Allow retracting flags on deleted posts even if you can't view deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333954/11682469)). Then again, if the post has already been deleted, it's likely the whole problem has already been dealt with. And if not, you could flag another post instead (for instance, someone promotes their library and their answers are deleted in the queue but they keep on posting).

Answer (score 6):

I would find this useful for one reason: my custom moderator flags often contain extensive Markdown to link posts, often that has to be hand-tweaked to be short enough to fit in the character limit (for example, `these posts ([1](/a/12345), [2](/a/23456), [3](/a/34565)) are all spam for $site (See [here](//link.to/context) for more posts from this campaign)`).

If I had some way of getting the Markdown, this wouldn't be an issue, but a simple copy/paste of the flag text doesn't get me what I need to recreate the flag.

This often comes up for flagging bad reviewers: I frequently stumble across additional bad reviews by the same people, but I don't always save the original flag text to add the additional reviews.