Is there a way to edit a custom flag?
I flagged an answer as possible AI content. In my explanation of the flag, one of the reasons I gave for this answer smelling like AI is because, at the time of my flag, the linked source at the bottom of the answer went to a "page not found". (That was not the only reason, but it's the one I want to update).
The link has since been changed by the answerer. However, the link now goes to a page that has nothing to do with the question or the answer.
Is there a way to edit my flag so what it says matches the current state of that answer?

You'll have to retract and re-flag, but you don't really need to in this case. If mods see a mismatch between minor details in the flag and the current state of the answers, most mods check revisions if that detail even matters to the flag handling process

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405245/allow-to-edit-a-custom-mod-flag

@Zoe-Savethedatadump IIRC a normal user can retract a flag, but can't flag again, right?!

@jps that restriction does not apply to mod flags
