# Plagiarism flags on deleted posts cannot be retracted

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, plagiarism, flag-history

I have flagged a [duplicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208665/when-using-google-app-script-to-export-a-sheet-to-pdf-how-do-you-specify-a-cust/76862409#76862409) as plagiarism which later got deleted. Since the user does not seem to be a serial plagiarizer, I don't think my flag serves any purpose anymore. Hence, I wanted to retract it.

I can still see the flag as pending on my flagging history page:

[image: plagiarism flag pending]

But when I try to retract it, it only shows me the mod flag option:

[image: only mod attention flag option]

This seems like a bug concerning plagiarism flags on deleted posts. It doesn't seem to affect moderators' ability to see the flag though.

Comment: p.s. I have tried using [userscripts which enable you to retract your flags from your flag history page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333954/allow-retracting-flags-on-deleted-posts-even-if-you-cant-view-deleted-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1) (primarily to help users with less than 10k rep) and it didn't work for plagiarism flags at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just noticed that I can retract my flag now. This should be marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

See the screenshot:

[image: now you can retract your plagiarism flags]

Comment: Interesting question, what happens if you are <10k, flag the post, post becomes deleted, but you decide to retract the flag. I am not sure, but probably the flag becomes accepted with the post deletion.

Comment: @peterh no, I don't think they'd be marked as helpful when the post gets deleted (some flags would, but not plagiarism ones; and it has nothing to do with whether the flagger has less or more than 10k rep). There are userscripts to help you retract your flags on deleted posts if you have less than 10k rep though: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333954/allow-retracting-flags-on-deleted-posts-even-if-you-cant-view-deleted-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok but so the <10k flagger has no more way to retract the flag, even if he would want to.

Comment: @peterh They don't have a way to retract a mod flag or a plagiarism flags by default using the SE software. I am not sure if those userscripts (that I have linked) are maintained, so it seems that users with less than 10k rep, as of now, have no way of retracting mod/plagiarism flags on deleted posts (other flags will be marked as helpful when a post gets deleted). Unless they go and write their own userscript to handle that. Is that unfair? Yes.